# Dplyr grouped percentages in different timeframes

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data in the following format:

```
  DATE     GROUP     EVENT    ELIGIBLE
2021-3-9     A         1         1
2021-3-1     A         0         0
2021-3-1     B         0         1
2021-2-20    B         1         1
```

I would like to group the data by the `GROUP` column and then add three new columns that calculate by group the sum of (EVENT / ELIGIBLE) for the following time frames. Last 3 months, 3 months back to six months back, and the last year.

I have calculated the overall percentage without separate timeframes by doing the following:

```
grouped <-   data %>% 
              
             filter(ELIGIBLE == 1 ) %>% 

             group_by(GROUP) %>%

             mutate(count_Eligible = sum(ELIGIBLE == 1 )) %>%                
                
             mutate(count_events = sum(EVENT == 1 )) %>%

             mutate(Percentage = round(100*count_events/count_Eligible,2))
```

I am wondering what the cleanest way would be to add the three different percentages within the timeframes. So far I have pulled the dates to do the filtering with the following code:

```
today <- Sys.Date()

three_month_lookback <- as.Date(today) - months(3)

six_month_lookback <- as.Date(today) - months(6)

one_year_lookback <- as.Date(today) - months(12)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can create a function to do the calculation

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

f1 <- function(data) {
    data %>% 
          
         filter(ELIGIBLE == 1 ) %>% 

         group_by(GROUP) %>%

         transmute(count_Eligible = sum(ELIGIBLE == 1 ),                    
                 count_events = sum(EVENT == 1 ), 
         Percentage = round(100*count_events/count_Eligible,2))


   }
```

Then, loop over the 'lookback' periods, subset the data based on the 'DATE' column and apply the function

```
map2_dfr(list(three_month_lookback, six_month_lookback, 
       one_year_lookback) list(today(), three_month_lookback, today()),
        ~ data %>%
           mutate(DATE = as.Date(DATE)) %>%
           filter(DATE >= .x,  DATE <= .y) %>%
           f1(.), .id = 'grp'
    )
```

If we need to combine by columns

```
map2(list(three_month_lookback, six_month_lookback, 
       one_year_lookback) list(today(), three_month_lookback, today()),
        ~ data %>%
           mutate(DATE = as.Date(DATE)) %>%
           filter(DATE >= .x,  DATE <= .y) %>%
           f1(.)
    ) %>%
      reduce(full_join, by = "GROUP")
```

Comment: This looks good thank you, however I dont think it accounts for the second time frame since that will be >= six month_lookback and <= three_month_lookback

Comment: Getting `Error: Problem with mutate() input DATE. x object DATE not found i Input DATE is as.Date(DATE)`. What is that mutate line doing?

Comment: @GNMO11 Please check the column name of your data.  In the example showed, it is `DATE`.  `mutate` is converting the column 'DATE' to `Date` class

Comment: @GNMO11 Is it possible that your data may not have any rows for at least one of those loop.  My understanding is that after the `filter(DATE >= .x,  DATE <= .y)`, it may return 0 rows for any of the cases

Comment: Ahh yes it was an issue with the column name. It seems to be working now giving three different dataframes, what is the easiest way to combine all three into one?

Comment: It seems to be adding rows instead of columns.

Comment: @GNMO11 You didnt tell me which way to combine earlier

Comment: So I am looking for:

    `time_frame_1_percentage    time_frame_2_percentage  
    time_frame_3_percentage
    A
    B
    C`

It looks like it is currently:

    `percentage
    A
    B
    C
    A
   B
   C
   A
   B
  C`

Comment: @GNMO11 I updated with `reduce` and `full_join`